# Go to new record in parent form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I have an Access form with a subform that has a subform, called Parent, Middle and Child. Upon an event in Child I want Middle to jump to a new record. I have tried

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Middle", acNewRec
```

However this produces an error, as the form "Middle" itself is not open. Giving it focus and calling the GotFocus function does not work either (probably because while I'm editing the Child, the Middle form still has focus).

Could anyone suggest a way I could jump to a new record in the Middle form?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the form `Middle`, create a new public method:

```
Public Sub MoveToNextRecord()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acNext
End Sub
```

In the form `Child`, you call the method with

```
Parent.MoveToNextRecord
```